# dictionaryWithContentsOfFile from the file string

Tags: objective-c, nsdictionary

I want to load a `NSDictionary` from a plist and I have the plist string in memory, I don't have the plist file. `NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:` only accepts file name, it won't accept file string. How can I load the `NSDictionary` with a plist file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you go...

```
NSData * data = [yourString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSString *errorDesc = nil;
NSPropertyListFormat format;
NSDictionary * dict = (NSDictionary*)[NSPropertyListSerialization
                                      propertyListFromData:data
                                      mutabilityOption:NSPropertyListMutableContainersAndLeaves
                                      format:&format
                                      errorDescription:&errorDesc];
```